# Throttling file operations

Tags: c#, task, throttling

I have a byte array that I want to persist in a file. But, I don't want to write to file each time it is updated because it can be updated very frequently. Currently I am planning to use an approach similar to following;

```
class ThrottleTest
{
    private byte[] _internal_data = new byte[256];

    CancellationTokenSource _cancel_saving = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public void write_to_file()
    {
        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file.data", _internal_data);
        }, _cancel_saving.Token);
    }

    public void operation_that_update_internal_data()
    {
        // cancel writing previous update
        _cancel_saving.Cancel();
        /*
         *  operate on _internal_data
         */

        write_to_file();
    }

    public void another_operation_that_update_internal_data()
    {
        // cancel writing previous update
        _cancel_saving.Cancel();
        /*
         *  operate on _internal_data
         */

        write_to_file();
    }
}
```

I don't think this approach would work, because, when I cancel the token once, it will be canceled forever, so it will never write to the file.

First of all, I was wondering if I am on the right track here, and above code can be made to work. If not, what would be the best approach to achieve this behaviour. Moreover, is there a practical way to generalize it to `Dictionary<string,byte[]>`, where any `byte[]` can be modified independently?

Comment: Is debouncing the correct term here?

Comment: Yeah debounce is probably where you are at, is this multi threaded?

Comment: @MichaelRandall it is multithreaded, but guaranteed to be not multiprocessed

Comment: What does `multiprocessed` mean?

Comment: I mean multiple threads from the same process can update the data, but more than one process will not be modifying the underlying file simultaneously.

Comment: You'd have to implement coalesced writes. Along the lines "If the incoming REQUEST is a write, the write-buffer attempts to add it to the queue of outstanding write-buffer entries by calling the function notpres_wb. If the request matches the line of another outstanding write, it is coalesced with the previous write access. Each line conceptually includes a bit-vector to account for such coalescing."

Answer (score 0):

I would start writing to file by cancelling first the previous operation.
I would also include the cancellation token in the Delay task.

```
CancellationTokenSource _cancel_saving;

public void write_to_file()
{
    _cancel_saving?.Cancel();
    _cancel_saving = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Delay(1000, _cancel_saving.Token).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file.data", _internal_data);
    }, _cancel_saving.Token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
public class ThrottleTest
{
    private byte[] _internal_data = new byte[256];

    private Subject<Unit> _write_to_file = new Subject<Unit>();

    public ThrottleTest()
    {
        _write_to_file
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
            .Subscribe(_ => File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file.data", _internal_data));
    }

    public void write_to_file()
    {
        _write_to_file.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    public void operation_that_update_internal_data()
    {
        /*
         *  operate on _internal_data
         */

        write_to_file();
    }

    public void another_operation_that_update_internal_data()
    {
        /*
         *  operate on _internal_data
         */

        write_to_file();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your context seems a little odd to me. You are writing all of the bytes, and not using a stream. Putting aside your issue with the cancellation token, delaying a write by 1 second won't reduce the overall load or overall throughput to disk.

This answer has the following assumptions:

- You are using an SSD and are concerned about hardware lifetime
- This is a low priority activity, where some data loss will be tolerated
- This is not a logging activity (otherwise an append to file would work better with a `BufferedStream`)
- This is likely the saving of a serialized C# object tree to disk in case the power goes out
- You don't want every change made to the object tree to result in a write to disk.
- You don't want to write to disk every second if there has been no change to the object tree.
- It should write to disk right away if there hasn't been a write for N seconds
- It should wait if there has been a write recently.

Having the WriteAllBytes step as the throttle point is not ideal.

Usage:

```
rootObject.subObject.value = 9;
rootObject.Save(token);
```

Support code:

```
TimeSpan minimumDiskInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
DateTime lastSaveAt = DateTime.MinValue;
bool alreadyQueued = false;
public void Save(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (alreadyQueued) //TODO: Interlocked with long instead for atomic memory barrier
        return;
        
    alreadyQueued = true; //TODO: Interlocked with long instead for atomic memory barrier

    var thisSaveAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var sinceLastSave = thisSaveAt.Subtract(lastSaveAt);
    var difference = TimeSpan.TotalSeconds - sinceLastSave.TotalSeconds;
    if (difference < 0)
    { 
        
        //It has been a while - no need to delay
        SaveNow();
    }
    else
    {
        //It was done recently
        
    T   Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(difference).ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            SaveNow();
        }, _cancel_saving.Token);   
    }
}

object fileAccessSync = new object();
public void SaveNow()
{
    alreadyQueued = false; //TODO: Interlocked with long instead for atomic memory barrier
    byte[] serializedBytes = Serialise(this)
    lock (fileAccessSync)
    {
        File.WriteAllBytes("path/to/file.data", serializedBytes);
    }
}
```